# Lua LGI unpack GLib.Variant object

Tags: lua, dbus, awesome-wm, lgi

I'm trying to get password from keyring for [awesome-wm](https://awesomewm.org/) session (using DBus via [lgi](https://github.com/pavouk/lgi) library).

I'm able to find keyring entry path, open communication session and unlock entry.
Then I call `GetSecrets` method and store result into `secret` variable.
According to the documentation it is supposed to be a [struct Secret](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/secret-service/ch14.html#type-Secret). Seems like `lgi` cannot handle this type and passes it as `userdata` type (at least I wasn't able to make it give access to struct fields). Is there a way to get `struct Secret` `value` field contents without writing custom C handler?

Here is the code:

```
local bus = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SESSION, nil)

local attr = {}
attr[1] = {attribute = "value"} -- attribute-value pair to search for

-- search for secret path
local name = "org.freedesktop.secrets"
local object = "/org/freedesktop/secrets"
local interface = "org.freedesktop.Secret.Service"
local method = "SearchItems"
local message = Gio.DBusMessage.new_method_call(name, object, interface, method)
message:set_body(GLib.Variant("(a{ss})", attr))

local result, err = bus:send_message_with_reply_sync(message, Gio.DBusSendMessageFlags.NONE,
                                                     -1, nil)
local location
for _, l in result:get_body():pairs() do
   if #l > 0 then location = l[1] end
end
print(location) -- returns "/org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/Default/1"

-- open session
local name = "org.freedesktop.secrets"
local object = "/org/freedesktop/secrets"
local interface = "org.freedesktop.Secret.Service"
local method = "OpenSession"
local message = Gio.DBusMessage.new_method_call(name, object, interface, method)
message:set_body(GLib.Variant("(sv)", {"plain", GLib.Variant("s", "")}))

local result, err = bus:send_message_with_reply_sync(message, Gio.DBusSendMessageFlags.NONE,
                                                     -1, nil)
local session = result:get_body()[2]
print(session) -- returns "/org/freedesktop/secrets/session/s4"

-- unlock key
local name = "org.freedesktop.secrets"
local object = "/org/freedesktop/secrets"
local interface = "org.freedesktop.Secret.Service"
local method = "Unlock"
local message = Gio.DBusMessage.new_method_call(name, object, interface, method)
message:set_body(GLib.Variant("(ao)", {{location}}))
local result, err = bus:send_message_with_reply_sync(message, Gio.DBusSendMessageFlags.NONE,
                                                     -1, nil)
-- at this point key property "Locked" if false. tested using d-feet

-- get secret
local name = "org.freedesktop.secrets"
local object = "/org/freedesktop/secrets"
local interface = "org.freedesktop.Secret.Service"
local method = "GetSecrets"
local message = Gio.DBusMessage.new_method_call(name, object, interface, method)
message:set_body(GLib.Variant("(aoo)", {{location},session}))

local result, err = bus:send_message_with_reply_sync(message, Gio.DBusSendMessageFlags.NONE,
                                                     -1, nil)
local secret = result:get_body()
print(#secret) -- returns "1"
print(secret)  -- returns table address
print(type(secret))  -- returns "userdata"

-- lock key
local name = "org.freedesktop.secrets"
local object = "/org/freedesktop/secrets"
local interface = "org.freedesktop.Secret.Service"
local method = "Lock"
local message = Gio.DBusMessage.new_method_call(name, object, interface, method)
message:set_body(GLib.Variant("(ao)", {{location}}))
local result, err = bus:send_message_with_reply_sync(message, Gio.DBusSendMessageFlags.NONE,
                                                     -1, nil)

-- close session
local name = "org.freedesktop.secrets"
local object = location
local interface = "org.freedesktop.Secret.Session"
local method = "Close"
local message = Gio.DBusMessage.new_method_call(name, object, interface, method)
local result, err = bus:send_message_with_reply_sync(message, Gio.DBusSendMessageFlags.NONE,
                                                     -1, nil)
```

## edit

When I do `print(secret)`, `lgi.rec 0x7f57d0014960:GLib.Variant` is returned.
So, `secret` is an object. How can I retrieve `value` field from `GLib.Variant` object?

## edit 2

`secret:get_data_as_bytes():get_data()` dumps struct in bytearray form; `secret:print()` returns formatted string of struct. I wonder if there's a better way.

## edit 3

type of `secret` variable is `(a{o(oayays)})`
Code to recreate an object of that type:

```
local lgi       = require     'lgi'
local Gio       = lgi.require 'Gio'
local GLib      = lgi.require 'GLib'

local var = GLib.Variant("(a{o(oayays)})", {{["/path/to/object"]={"/path/to/session","parameters","value","content_type"}}})
```

Comment: You could check if the userdata has a metatable with a `__index` metamethod to access the fields of the struct.

Comment: @cyclaminist turns out that `secret` is an object of type `GLib.Variant`. Now I need to figure out how to get `value` from it.

Answer (score 1):

(Note that I didn't install this password manager or try any of this at all)

Last time I asked the author of LGI about such issue, the answer was:

> I have submitted fix to Variant which restores this functionality.  So
>   an example of use will be:
>
> local function called_from_C(userdata)
>     local variant = GLib.Variant(userdata)
>     print(variant)
>   end
>
> if you have to support older (well, released :) lgi versions, you can
>   use undocumented way:
>
> local core = require 'lgi.core'
>      local function called_from_C(userdata)
>        local variant = core.record.new(GLib.Variant, userdata)
>        print(variant)
>      end

Note that there is other ways. To work around another such bugs, I also once created a C Lua plugin and just wrote that code in C. That's actually rather trivial with Lua [2].

Another way, if you use LuaJIT, is to use the built-in FFI to just-in-time compile the struct definition into a Lua object [1].

Finally, if the question is more about how to unpack "working" GVariant values once they are consumed properly by LGI, look at my code for this here https://github.com/Elv13/wirefu/blob/master/proxy.lua

[1] http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_api.html

[2] https://github.com/Elv13/lua_async_binding/blob/master/src/luabridge.c#L407

Comment: I don't want to add code in C mainly from code distribution point of view. I've added a small piece of code to recreate an object of required type. Maybe you could take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found a solution. To unpack a value of a complex type, for example `(a{o(oayays)})`, one should use `get_child_value` function.

```
secret:get_child_value(0):get_child_value(0):get_child_value(1):get_child_value(2).value
```

Explanation: index tuple; index array; index dict; index tuple